# Htaccess Rewrite Cond or redirectmatch to remove query string from front of URL

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I remember that redirectmatch can't handle question marks but how can I match this url:

```
http://www.mysite.com/es/?lang=es&url=index.php&option=com_virtuemart&page=shop.browse&category_id=42&product_type_id=1&product_type_1etcetcetc`
```

to remove the `lang=es&url=` from before the index.php when there is a folder name present?

My problem would be solved if I could either remove the /es/ folder from the URL when presented with the `?lang=es&url=` query string or I could remove the query string `?lang=es&url=` from the URL when the folder is /es/

There are about 11 languages, with country codes fr, de, etc and one odd one out zh-CN. This is just past my capabilites at the moment. Thanks for taking the time to read this and any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: mainly working now. I'm just having a small problem with the zh-CN language as it seems to be acting differently from the other en, fr, de etc, languages which are doing what I want, staying in English even when double clicking on another language. However, the zh-CN language redirects to the homepage with http://www.seed-city.com/?lang=zh-CN&url=index.php&zh-CN

I currently have this in my htaccess file:

`RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/../

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} lang=..&url=index.php&(.*)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1index.php?%1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(zh-CN|zh-TW)/ [NC]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} lang=([a-z]{2}|zh-CN|zh-TW)&url=index.php&(.*) [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1index.php?%1 [R=301,L]`

I have much more after but this is the relevant part. Thanks for your time. Natastna2.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your requirement properly this will work in your .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/es/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} lang=es&url=index.php&(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1index.php?%1 [R=301,L]
```

Using above role a URL like this: `http://www.mysite.com/es/?lang=es&url=index.php&option=com_virtuemart&page=shop.browse&category_id=42&product_type_id=1&product_type_1etc`

will be redirected to:
`http://www.mysite.com/es/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&page=shop.browse&category_id=42&product_type_id=1&product_type_1etc`

## EDIT

As per your edited section here are the rewrite rules that should work for now:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/../
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} lang=..&url=index.php&(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1index.php?%1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(zh-CN|zh-TW)/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} lang=(zh-CN|zh-TW)&url=index.php&(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1index.php?%2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Everything is working perfectly now. I needed one more rule in the end to cover everything but your answers were invaluable. I  have ended up with `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/../  
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} lang=(zh-CN|zh-TW)&url=index.php&(.*)  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1index.php?%2 [R=301,L]`   @anubhava thanks again.